# Query from XML Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This results are located in XML column of the table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<client id_issue="5488">
<surname value="Hasanov"/>
<name value="Mehman"/>
<middle_name value="Adil"/>
<date_birth value="1986-05-19"/>
</client>
```

I want to query the values of the `surname`,`name`,`middle_name` and `date_birth` from XML column.

Like below:

```
surname    name    middle_name    date_birth` 
----------------------------------------------   
Hasanov    Mehman   Adil         1986-05-19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XQuery as follows:

```
DECLARE @q XML= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <client id_issue="5488">
        <surname value="Hasanov"/>
        <name value="Mehman"/>
        <middle_name value="Adil"/>
        <date_birth value="1986-05-19"/>
    </client>';

SELECT @q.value('(client/surname/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS surname,
       @q.value('(client/name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS name,
       @q.value('(client/middle_name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS middle_name,
       @q.value('(client/date_birth/@value)[1]', 'date') AS date_birth;
```

Read more about XQuery: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

If you have a table and you are going to parse the xml inside the table you can try this, which is similar to above mentioned solution:

Suppose that you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    msg XML
);
```

and you have inserted some data like this into that table:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest
VALUES
(1,
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <client id_issue="5488">
        <surname value="Hasanov"/>
        <name value="Mehman"/>
        <middle_name value="Adil"/>
        <date_birth value="1986-05-19"/>
    </client>'),
(2,
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <client id_issue="5488">
        <surname value="Alimov"/>
        <name value="Ghader"/>
        <middle_name value="Ragman"/>
        <date_birth value="1950-04-20"/>
    </client>');
```

So you can simply parse it using XQuery as:

```
SELECT msg.value('(client/surname/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS surname,
       msg.value('(client/name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS name,
       msg.value('(client/middle_name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS middle_name,
       msg.value('(client/date_birth/@value)[1]', 'date') AS date_birth
FROM tblTest;
```

Even if your `msg` does not have XML data type(for example it would be `varchar(max)`) then you need to cast it to xml prior to querying using XQuery like this:

```
SELECT CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/surname/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS surname,
       CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS name,
       CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/middle_name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS middle_name,
       CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/date_birth/@value)[1]', 'date') AS date_birth
FROM tblTest;
```

Executing the above query, you'll get the following error:

> unable to switch the encoding

You can rewrite it as:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '') AS XML).value('(client/surname/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS surname,
       CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '') AS XML).value('(client/name/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [name],
       CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '') AS XML).value('(client/middle_name/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS middle_name,
       CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '') AS XML).value('(client/date_birth/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')AS date_birth
FROM tblTest;
```

And finally if you need to use the output of the aforementioned query in other query(like JOIN to to other relation) you can put it as a subquery and use it.

```
SELECT K.surname,
       K.name,
       K.middle_name,
       K.date_birth
FROM
(
    SELECT msg.value('(client/surname/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS surname,
           msg.value('(client/name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS name,
           msg.value('(client/middle_name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS middle_name,
           msg.value('(client/date_birth/@value)[1]', 'date') AS date_birth
    FROM tblTest
) AS K INNER JOIN ...
```

Comment: It is include for one select.i have table called data and there is one content column contain XML data.column type is ntext.so i need to join this data table with other table and also to read the contents of content table data with every select

Comment: @garibhasanov I have updated the answer and include the guide which leads you to extract data from XML stored in a table

Comment: SELECT CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/surname/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS surname,
       CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS name,
       CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/middle_name/@value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS middle_name,
       CAST(msg AS XML).value('(client/date_birth/@value)[1]', 'date') AS date_birth
FROM tblTest;

After using above query I got an error (XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding)

Comment: Then I have try with this following query.Worked.

SELECT  
CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '')
AS XML).value('(client/ surname/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS surname,
CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '')
AS XML).value('(client/ name/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [name],
CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '')
AS XML).value('(client/ middle_name/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS middle_name,

Comment: @garibhasanov I have updated the answer and include your great comment. thanks. Do not forget to click on the UpVote, if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT s.c.value('@id_issue', 'INT') AS id_issue
     ,s.c.value('surname[1]/@value', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS surname
     ,s.c.value('name[1]/@value', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS name
     ,s.c.value('middle_name[1]/@value', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS middle_name
     ,s.c.value('date_birth[1]/@value', 'DATE') AS dob
FROM tab
CROSS APPLY tab.col.nodes('/client') s(c);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0cf1913657664acbe810887fe54c7c9)**

---

**EDIT:**

> I have Got the error...Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml. my xml column type is ntext

[`NTEXT` is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). You could cast NTEXT to XML and then parse it.

```
SELECT s.c.value('@id_issue', 'INT') AS id_issue
     ,s.c.value('surname[1]/@value', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS surname
     ,s.c.value('name[1]/@value', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS name
     ,s.c.value('middle_name[1]/@value', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS middle_name
     ,s.c.value('date_birth[1]/@value', 'DATE') AS dob
FROM tab
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST(REPLACE(CAST(tab.col AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','') AS XML)) sub(col)
CROSS APPLY sub.col.nodes('/client') s(c)
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1398230625aa5ed3b23e3e3d68d4bd9a)**

Comment: I have Got the error...Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.  my xml column type is ntext

Comment: Execution minute is 04:06 but still no result.

Comment: Execution minute is 04:06 but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with this query

```
SELECT

CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '')
AS XML).value('(client/ surname/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS surname,

CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '')
AS XML).value('(client/ name/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [name],

CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '')
AS XML).value('(client/ middle_name/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS middle_name,

CAST(REPLACE(CAST([msg] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'encoding="utf-8"', '')
AS XML).value('(client/ date_birth/@value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS date_birth
```